# Why is a searchable custom attribute not part of search query with Google Retail API?

Tags: google-api-php-client

I created a site-wide custom attribute with a "searchable" property, created a product with this property. The custom attribute values can be seen as facets and used as filter, but **are not searchable** from a query.

I ran out of ideas to try!

I attached below the screen captures showing all the details from the Google Retail API console.

1. A catalog custom attribute with a "searchable" property:

```
$response = $client->addCatalogAttribute( $formattedAttributesConfig, new CatalogAttribute( [
                'key'                      => 'attributes.vendors_1',
                'dynamic_facetable_option' => DynamicFacetableOption::DYNAMIC_FACETABLE_DISABLED,
                'searchable_option'        => SearchableOption::SEARCHABLE_ENABLED,
                'indexable_option'         => IndexableOption::INDEXABLE_ENABLED,
            ] ) );
```

[image]

2. A result with the custom attribute as a facet:

```
$product->setAttributes( [
                'vendors_1' => new CustomAttribute( [ 'text' => [ 'vendor123', 'vendor456' ] ] )
            ] );
```

[image]

3. But a query on the custom attribute content returns no results:
   [image: Query does not find the custom attribute content]

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

It appears in fact that custom attributes are searchable as expected.

But search on 'vendor123' is a kind of exception.
'vendor12', 'vendor1', 'vendor 1', 'vendor 12' work fine.

Strange!